# Does setting Enabled = 1 override postDate in front end forms?

Tags: frontend

I have a front end form where I set have

```
<input type="hidden" name="enabled" value="1">
```

I also need to set the postDate to a date in the future. Does setting enabled = 1 reset the postDate in all cases? Or should I just forego the enabled form field altogether in favor of Setting postDate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting `enabled = 1` will not alter your postDate.

If you were to set a postDate in the future, the entry would simply not show up (by default).
However, if you'd want enabled entries with a future postDate to show up in your template results, use:

```
{% set futureEntries = craft.entries.status('pending') %}
```

If you do not use the `status` criterium, it will default to `live`, which is all enabled entries with a postDate in the past. So, it all depends on how you display the entries, not so much on how you save them.

Also, see [this Craft docs information on status](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/craft.entries#status).